# Sequelize does not create associations in hook

Tags: node.js, sqlite, sequelize.js, hook

I'm having the following source:

```js
    // file: db/models/a.js
    const a = db.define('ModelA', {})
    
    a.addHook('beforeSync', function() {
      a.hasMany(db.models.ModelB, {
        foreignKey: 'refA'
      })
    })
    
    // file: db/models/b.js
    const b = db.define('ModelB', {})
    
    b.addHook('beforeSync', function() {
      b.belongsTo(db.models.ModelA, {
        foreignKey: 'refA'
      })
    })
    
    // file: db.js
    db.sync({force: true})
```

When I run it, both hooks are called but when I try to do something like `db.models.ModelA.findByPk(..., {include: [db.models.ModelB] })`, it says "SequelizeDatabaseError: SQLITE_ERROR: no such column: ModelA.refA". I checked the sqlite file and indeed, no colum called "refA" has been created.

When I do the same outside the hook, it works perfectly. So I wonder why it's not working inside the hook.

My idea was to use the hook system instead of implementing and calling an associate() function.

Anyone has any idea why it does not create my columns?

Comment: at hook, we cannot call `hasMany`

Comment: Thank you @MERN. But what's the reason or is there any hint in the documentation?

Comment: you can use hasMany outside hook

Comment: why you are using `beforeSync` hook?

Comment: Because I think it's a more clean way than implementing a separate "associate" class method I need to call anywhere outside. Furthermore "the outside" don't need to know anything about the associations (except where I need them) and I don't have to take care myself that the associate method ist getting called because Sequelize would do it for me...

Comment: then, you can use migrate script instead of `sync({force: true})`